# Where can I get the 11.04 kernel .config file?

Tags: 11.04, kernel

I'm using Maverick with the latest available kernels on kernel.org and building them myself. Until now I've been basing my configuration off the stock Maverick kernel and accepting the `make oldconfig` defaults. I've been doing this for 3 major releases now so I figure I'm starting to slip behind the current "standard".

I would like to re-base my kernels off the new Natty `.config` file. Is this available somewhere online or do I have to download the whole kernel package and extract it?

Edit: I've manually pulled in the config from the latest Natty kernel package and I can confirm that I propbably should have done this sooner. A lot of differences between my old "evolved" config and the Natty default. Now if I could just do this without 20 minutes of hunting and downloading the package so I can re-base in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The kernel team has posted the configs for Natty here:

- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/configs/natty/

Sources:

- [Mailing list post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-March/032763.html)
- [Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Configs/MaverickToNatty) detailing the changes between 10.10 and 11.04

Answer (score 35):

Each `linux-image` package contains the exact configuration file that it was built with in `/boot/config-*`.  To see the configuration file for the currently running Linux kernel, do:

- `less /boot/config-$(uname -r)`

I have checked with the Ubuntu kernel people (on Freenode `#ubuntu-kernel`) and they have confirmed my belief that there isn't really "*the* config", but it is actually constructed at build/compile time by including a number of `Kconfig` files; these depend on the exact architecture and target (desktop/server/cloud).  You should be able to read that (short) conversation at:

- [irclogs.ubuntu.com/2011/03/15/#ubuntu-kernel.html#t13:48](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2011/03/15/%23ubuntu-kernel.html#t13:48)

A list of that variety can be found using **packages.ubuntu.com** and the following search:

- [packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=config-2.6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=natty&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=config-2.6)

Hunting, around, it would appear that the `.config` is also included in the `linux-headers-*` packages.  These are `.deb` files (which are simple `.ar` archives that will open with `file-roller`) and only about 800 kB each.  If you know the particular target, architecture and version you're after, you can grab these straight from Launchpad or from the archive itself:

1. [archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/**linux-header-2.6***.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/)
2. then look in `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6*/``.config`

If you want to automate the whole process into one command, you could try the following; make sure you keep it all on one line!

- `wget -qO- http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-2.6.38-6-generic_2.6.38-6.34_i386.deb | dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile /dev/stdin | tar Ox --wildcards './usr/src/*/.config'`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for investigating this. Having read the irclog, it doesn't look like I'm going to get what I want without significant download. Automation-wise, it's still easier to grab the package and extract its `/boot-config-*` than trying to emulate the wizardry they use to autogen them at build-time. It's a shame there isn't a way of grabbing one file from a package online (or is there?)

Comment: I think I'll ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

On my Ubuntu 11.10 system the kernel config is in the file '/boot/config-3.0.0-12-generic'.

Comment: The question is for 11.04, not 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu git kernel repository**

The `debian/` metadata which contains the configs, and the kernel tree are tracked both in a single git repository per release: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git/

The repo then has a tag for each kernel package, e.g. in my Ubuntu 18.04, I have the package `linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic`, which I'm guessing corresponds to the tag: `Ubuntu-4.15.0-36.39`.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile explains how to compile the kernel, and therefore how to configure it and how configs are merged into the final config.

The configs all seem to be under [`debian.master/config/ARCH`](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git/tree/debian.master/config?h=Ubuntu-4.15.0-36.39) which contains:

```
config.common.ubuntu
config.common.ports
amd64/config.common.amd64
amd64/config.flavour.generic
amd64/config.flavour.lowlatency
```

so I'm guessing that `linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic` will merge `config.common.ubuntu`, `config.common.amd64` and `config.flavour.generic`.

The script that does the merging seems to be [debian/scripts/misc/kernelconfig](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git/tree/debian/scripts/misc/kernelconfig?h=Ubuntu-4.15.0-36.39) and it contains the comment:

```
# Merge configs
# We merge config.common.ubuntu + config.common.<arch> +
# config.flavour.<flavour>
```

TODO: there is also an [`debian.master/config/annotations`](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git/tree/debian.master/config/annotations?h=Ubuntu-4.15.0-36.39) file which seems to contain the value for each config for each arch, how is that used?

Someone should confirm all that by running build scripts in verbose mode somehow, but I'm lazy now, you can build with:

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git linux
cd linux
git checkout Ubuntu-4.15.0-36.39
fakeroot debian/rules clean
debian/rules updateconfigs
fakeroot debian/rules build-generic
```

I have then confirmed that this produces the exact same config that I have locally:

```
diff debian/build/build-generic/.config /boot/config-4.15.0-36-generic
```

Note that the Ubuntu kernel git repo also has thousands of patches on top of upstream Linux, so just getting the right config won't be enough to reproduce behavior.

We can also triple check that the kernel we built matches the packaged one by looking at the start of `dmesg` of the boot, which contains:

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-36-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-031) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-36.39-generic 4.15.18)
```

**Config in the `.deb`**

As mentioned by others, the final full config is also present under:

```
/boot/config-4.15.0-36-generic
```

which correspond to each Linux kernel image:

```
/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
```

So, for other versions, we can find from which package those come from:

```
dpkg -S /boot/config-4.15.0-36-generic
```

which gives:

```
linux-modules-4.15.0-36-generic: /boot/config-4.15.0-36-generic
```

and then you can just download the `.deb` from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/linux-modules-4.15.0-36-generic 
 and extract it to get the config:

```
mkdir config
cd config
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-modules-4.15.0-36-generic_4.15.0-36.39_amd64.deb
ar x linux-modules-4.15.0-36-generic_4.15.0-36.39_amd64.deb
tar -xvf data.tar.xz
cat ./boot/config-4.15.0-36-generic
```

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.