# Download just one file from a package

Tags: package-management

I want one file from a built package that I don't have (and don't particularly want to download). Is there a service (Launchpad/Packages.Ubuntu.com/etc) where I can just go in and download the file I want?

The context for this is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28047/where-can-i-get-the-natty-kernel-config-file) where I want the latest `/boot/config-*` file from the latest available kernel package. The packages are quite large so I'd rather just download the comparatively tiny config file and build the kernel myself (I hack it around and customise it).

This may easily result in a "no, you can't do that" but I wanted to test the water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now posted this example on the bottom of the original question too, but for completeness I'll include it here aswell:

- `wget -qO- http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-2.6.38-6-generic_2.6.38-6.34_i386.deb | dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile /dev/stdin | tar Ox --wildcards './usr/src/*/.config`

This does not actually prevent downloading of the package file.  But with some further cunningness and ask `wget` to only fetch a particular range it would be possible, although not automatic.  If you have a wider and more in-depth interest in the subject, it is probably partially covered from the slides and video from a talk at FOSDEM few years ago:

- [archive.fosdem.org/2007/schedule/events/debian_delta_upgrades](http://archive.fosdem.org/2007/schedule/events/debian_delta_upgrades)

The case here is is only one file, or part of file has changed in a `.deb` package, how to extract that from the stack of `.ar+.gz+.tar` without causing a download of the full thing. (Disclaimer: I was one of the speakers).