# What's a simple way to recompile the kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I'm interested in compiling a new kernel under Ubuntu 12.04 x86 64 bit.

I found [this wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) which is basically a mirror for [this blog](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/compile-linux-kernel-3-2-for-ubuntu-11-10/) and there are a lot of steps (*git*, etc.) that appear useless to me.

With earlier releases/distros, I used to create a `.config` file and modify a `Makefile` if I needed to, then just run `make` and it's done.

Is there is a simple way to do this under Ubuntu?

Comment: Worth checking out: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Comment: It looks like the right way to build today is to checkout from git with a tag, then run the `fakeroot debian/rules ...` commands. See the answer by @Pilot6 at a [linked question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935858/how-to-compile-a-kernel-identical-to-apt-get-install-linux-image-xxx). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why is the title about *recompiling* a kernel?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### 1. Use `apt-get source` to download the Ubuntu version of the kernel

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

gives a folder that contains, for example:

```
linux-3.2.0                linux_3.2.0-26.41.dsc
linux_3.2.0-26.41.diff.gz  linux_3.2.0.orig.tar.gz
```

The bolded diff includes all the Ubuntu/Debian customizations.

#### 2. To build a stock kernel with your own `.config`, use the "old-fashioned" Debian `make-kpkg` method

This is the [alternate old-fashioned way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile#Alternate_Build_Method:_The_Old-Fashioned_Debian_Way) described in the wiki:

```
sudo apt-get install kernel-package
```

If you are compiling a kernel for the first time:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Then `cd` into the source directory (here, `linux-3.2.0`), and either run `make oldconfig` to create `.config` file with your running kernel's configuration, or copy a third-part `.config` to this directory.

Depending on whether you want a text or graphical config, install:

(Text)

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5 libncurses5-dev
```

(Graphical)

```
sudo apt-get install qt3-dev-tools libqt3-mt-dev
```

And then run:

(Text)

```
make menuconfig
```

(Graphical)

```
make xconfig
```

When done, just run:

```
fakeroot make-kpkg -j N --initrd --append-to-version=my-very-own-kernel kernel-image kernel-headers
```

where `N` is how many jobs to run in parallel (usually the number of CPUs you have), and `my-very-own-kernel` is a custom string to identify this build.

When done, the kernel image and header files will be ready as debs in the parent directory; you can install them with `sudo dpkg -i`, which will also take care of adding GRUB entries, etc.

Comment: why they tells you nothing about this diff, to me a diff is just a diff, it can contain everything.

Comment: I don't know, you would have to ask them (google for Canonical Kernel Team). I just told you how to build it ;)

Comment: ok, last question, how to apply this compressed diff? :D I have to go in the `linux-3.2.0` directory and run `patch -p1 <../patch.diff` ?

Comment: There's **no need** to apply the diff; `apt-get source ...` did that for you already!

Comment: Excuse me, but I am new to kernel compilation: when you say "Then cd into the source directory (here, linux-3.2.0)", where is that directory supposed to be? Should it be `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0" for this example?

Comment: Helpful answer. Only thing I miss the `make nconfig`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore without calling `make-kpkg` with `fakeroot`.  I get errors on "installing" the deb.  Editing the answer...

Comment: -1 You call it "old-fashioned," I call it outdated. `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs`, `fakeroot debian/rules clean`, `fakeroot debian/rules binary` is the correct, problem-free way.

Comment: This **does not work anymore in Ubuntu 18.04+**. Try `apt-get source linux-source` instead and follow the instructions on how to clone the git repo.

Comment: @rustyx doesn't work either, I get: `You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list`

Answer (score 23):

Here are the steps. *This procedure is based on [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/about-us)'s [How to: Compile Linux kernel 2.6](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html)--but modernized considerably.*

### Download and extract the source code of the kernel you wish to build.

You can get [upstream](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37147/what-are-the-differences-between-the-ubuntu-shipped-kernel-and-the-upstream-kern) kernel source code at [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/). Version [3.16.1](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ChangeLog-3.16.1) (the latest stable kernel as of this writing) will be used here. So you may need to modify these commands if you're using a different version.

Kernel source code is currently provided in .[tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)).[xz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) archives, so click the "tar.xz" link by whatever version you want:

[image: screenshot from kernel.org, showing kernel source archives available for download]

After [`cd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command))ing to the directory where you downloaded the archive, you can extract it with [`tar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/tar.1.html):

```
tar xf linux-3.16.1.tar.xz
```

### Install the necessary build tools and perform kernel configuration.

To get Ubuntu's [toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain) (`gcc`, `make`, and so forth) install the [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) metapackage:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Two reasonably user-friendly ways to configure what goes into your kernel are provided by the `make` targets `xconfig` and `menuconfig`.

`xconfig` runs a graphical configuration utility, while `menuconfig` is text-based (i.e., its interface appears fully within your terminal). Each requires some additional software *not* provided by [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential).

***To configure graphically***, install [libqt4-dev [image: Install libqt4-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libqt4-dev) and [pkg-config [image: Install pkg-config]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pkg-config) and run `make xconfig`:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev pkg-config
make xconfig
```

***To configure in the terminal***, install `libncurses5-dev` (thanks to [Hannu](https://askubuntu.com/users/289138/hannu) for this info) and run `make menuconfig`:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
make menuconfig
```

### Build the configured kernel.

First run this to compile the kernel and create [`vmlinuz`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux):

```
make
```

`vmlinuz` is "the kernel." Specifically, it is the kernel image that will be uncompressed and loaded into memory by [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRUB) or whatever other [boot loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_loader#BOOT-LOADER) you use.

Then build the [loadable kernel modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_module):

```
make modules
```

### Install your newly built kernel.

Assuming those `make` commands completed successfully, it's time to install the new kernel. First ***install the modules:***

```
sudo make modules_install
```

Then ***install the kernel*** itself:

```
sudo make install
```

That puts `vmlinuz-3.16.1` (a copy of `vmlinuz`), `config-3.16.1` (a text file storing kernel configuration parameters), and `System.map-3.16.1` (the [kernel symbol lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System.map)) in `/boot`. For more details, see [this comp.os.linux.misc post by Hadron](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.misc/2007-06/msg00679.html) and [`man installkernel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/installkernel.8.html).

### Final setup, so the kernel can be started and boot the system:

*This section is partly based on information in [Kernel/Compile](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile).*

With the kernel now where it needs to be, it needs:

- an entry in the [boot loader](https://askubuntu.com/tags/bootloader/info)'s configuration, so you can select and boot from it.
- an [initial RAM filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd), the environment from which the kernel loads drivers and mounts the [`/` filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_filesystem).

  (If you're installing an old kernel or have configured your kernel [to use devfs instead of the newer udev](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/293/How_Do_I_Make_an_initrd_image#comment_14), you may need or wish to set up an [initial ramdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) instead. If you know you need that instead, see [`man initrd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/mkinitrd.8.html).)

***Generate your initramfs*** with [`mkinitramfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/mkinitramfs.8.html):

```
cd /boot
sudo mkinitramfs -ko initrd.img-3.16.1 3.16.1
```

When you update the configuration of the GRUB2 boot loader--which has been [the default in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) since 9.10--[should automatically detect the new kernel](https://superuser.com/a/304190/105707) and add an option to boot from it.

```
sudo update-grub
```

### Try your kernel.

Now you can reboot to test out your new kernel. You may need to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during boot to see the GRUB boot menu where you can select between the different kernels that are installed.

To make your kernel (or another one) the default, see [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Comment: Step 3, `make menuconfig` requires `apt get install libncurses5-dev`

Comment: @Hannu thank you, I just completely forgot to mention that. 64-bit system users may require "ia32-libs" also for the support of 32-bit programs to run.

Comment: Could be better to find a version-independent package too... I'm not sure there is any though.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thank you. Is it OK now or should I delete it completely? I have no issue in doing that.

Comment: @Novice You've lessened material reproduced from the source; this is helpful. But there was still copied text together with your own and it was otherwise very similar. When relying mostly on one source, it's better to make something *inspired* or *educated* by it than a *version* of it. You should understand why what you're saying is right, avoid some of the source's shortcomings, and make something well suited to your audience (here, Ubuntu users). *I think we'll benefit from a "traditional" kernel compilation guide, so I've tried to improve this more. If you like, feel free to edit further.*

Comment: @EliahKagan Thank you very much, I'll take care from next time.

Comment: -1 This doesn't produce an _Ubuntu_ kernel. It doesn't even produce .deb files. This is a recipe for problems.

Comment: This is not the first time I've come back to this answer. Very useful for my ubuntu odroids, thank you for this.

Comment: Sorry, thought I added this link (useful for odroids): https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-xu4/software/building_kernel

Answer (score 3):

The quick instructions for building an *Ubuntu* kernel (as opposed to vanilla) can be found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel.

I won't copy the whole wiki, but I'll list the minimal steps to compile the version of the Ubuntu kernel that you currently have installed. (To get the most recent version, clone the kernel git repository of the upcoming Ubuntu release.) Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
# Get source code
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)

# Install dependencies
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)

# Compile
cd linux-4.4.0
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary

# Install (obviously the versions will be different)
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic_4.4.0-38.57_amd64.deb linux-headers-4.4.0-38_4.4.0-38.57_all.deb linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic_4.4.0-38.57_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu git kernel repository**

Following ideas from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile and with greater clarification of why I think that config look correct at [Where can I get the 11.04 kernel .config file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28047/where-can-i-get-the-11-04-kernel-config-file/1081647#1081647):

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git linux
cd linux
git checkout Ubuntu-4.15.0-36.39
fakeroot debian/rules clean
debian/rules updateconfigs
fakeroot debian/rules build-generic
cp debian/build/build-generic/.config .
make -j `nproc`
```

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.