# Change clock resolution to 1000 Hz

Tags: kernel, clock

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I need to change the **clock resolution** to **1000** Hz (now it's 250 Hz, the default value).

I understand that I have to set it and then recompile the **kernel**, as for example described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956206/change-linux-kernel-timer). It's not clear, though, how I can do it from the terminal, as for instance the suggested `make menuconfig` won't work.

Any tips?

My current settings are:

```
$ cat /boot/config-3.8.0-29-generic | grep HZ
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
CONFIG_RCU_FAST_NO_HZ=y
# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_250=y
# CONFIG_HZ_300 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_1000 is not set
CONFIG_HZ=250
CONFIG_MACHZ_WDT=m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in the end I just didn't know all the steps involved in order to recompile the kernel.
The instructions can be found in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163298/whats-a-simple-way-to-recompile-the-kernel).

Answer (score 1):

> make menuconfig won't work.

Might depend on a simple `$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev`.

Furthermore I'm not convinced just a simple `CONFIG_HZ_1000` will make you happy, there might be other problems raising from changing it.
I'd recommend taking a thorough look into that.