# How to install needed Qt packages to build kernel on 14.04?

Tags: kernel, package-management, compiling, dependencies, qt

I'm going to compile kernel on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, so I start with installing packages that I need:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential bin86 kernel-package libqt3-headers libqt3-mt-dev wget libncurses5 libncurses5-dev qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev
```

Everything is installed except `libqt3-headers` and `libqt3-mt-dev` packages. For those packages I got in terminal:

```
E: Unable to locate package libqt3-headers
E: Unable to locate package libqt3-mt-dev
```

I looked around and it seems like there is no those packages in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Why do you want Qt3 headers? I assume they have been removed from Ubuntu long ago, since the current Qt version is 5.3.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the tutorial on local Ubuntu forum, this tutorial exists since Ubuntu version 9.04 and it is regularly updated (last time is updated today for compiling kernel 3.16.1), maybe those packages remained from the older Ubuntu and it isn't changed (removed)...so I don't need those packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: *Based on what you already do have installed, just install [pkg-config [image: Install pkg-config]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pkg-config) and you should be good to go.*

Building the kernel uses Qt if you want to configure what goes into your kernel by running `make xconfig`. (Which you likely do, as this is one of the friendliest ways to do it.)

At least for any remotely recent kernel, you can use Qt 4 instead of Qt 3. You should install:

- [libqt4-dev [image: Install libqt4-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libqt4-dev), so the xconfig utility can link against Qt4, *and*
- [pkg-config [image: Install pkg-config]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pkg-config), so `make xconfig` can automatically discover the Qt4 headers installed by `libqt4-dev` and use them.

You can install those packages through the Software Center or with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev pkg-config
```

(For more information on `make xconfig`, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/513243/22949) to [What's a simple way to recompile the kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163298/whats-a-simple-way-to-recompile-the-kernel).)

You don't need *both* Qt3 and Qt4 headers: provided either is installed correctly and the system is configured so they'll be identified by `make xconfig` ([pkg-config is one way to faciliate this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config)), you don't need the other.

<sup>By the way, though there's no harm in doing so, it's *not* actually necessary to explicitly install `qt4-dev-tools`. `libqt4-dev` [declares](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libqt4-dev) the other necessary Qt4-related packages, such as `libqt4-dev-bin` and `qt4-qmake`, as dependencies, causing them to be automatically installed as well. You also only need the `ncurses` packages if you're going to run `make menuconfig` (which is a non-graphical alternative to `make xconfig`).</sup>

In your case, you already have [libqt4-dev [image: Install libqt4-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libqt4-dev) installed, so you can just install [pkg-config [image: Install pkg-config]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pkg-config).

Comment: This worked to enable me to run the Buildroot `make xconfig` cmd to view the Qt-based GUI configuration menu.

Answer (score 0):

Those packages belong to Qt version 3, which has become obsolete as the current version is 5.3. They are no longer included in repositories.

I don't know why you would need those packages anyway.

> If you've not built a kernel on your system before, there are some packages needed before you can successfully build. You can get these installed with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
> ```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Comment: So all packages that I need to compile latest stable kernel (3.16.1) will be installed using command that you provide?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential kernel-package libncurses5-dev bzip2 bin86 qt4-dev-tools  wget libncurses5 git-core nautilus-open-terminal
```

because you're using newer linux > 13.10