# How do I recompile my kernel without qt3?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, compiling, source, qt3

So I'm trying to recompile my kernel (it doesn't have uinput support but nm that). I followed the instructions on [How to install needed Qt packages to build kernel on 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520864/how-to-install-needed-qt-packages-to-build-kernel-on-14-04)
but

when I run `~/Downloads/linux-2.6.32.68$ make xconfig` I get this.

```
CHECK qt
Unable to find the QT3 installation. Please make sure that the QT3 development package is correctly installed and either install pkg-config or set the QTDIR environment variable to the correct location.
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `scripts/kconfig/.tmp_qtcheck', needed by `scripts/kconfig/qconf.o'.  Stop. make: *** [xconfig] Error 2
```

I think this may be an upgrade error since even though I have qt5 it complains that it can't find qt3. Asside from Nuke and Pave how can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install needed Qt packages to build kernel on 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520864/how-to-install-needed-qt-packages-to-build-kernel-on-14-04)

Comment: That answer didn't work for me. My Ubuntu doggedly looks for QT3. It doesn't seem to care that I have QT5. Is there a variable somewhere to fix?

Comment: I'm just gonna Nuke and Pave.

Comment: @steeldriver this is not a dupe, the OP mentions that the solutions there failed for him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you need to install some libraries do not exist for Trusty or you have to take the road for which the libraries are not needed.

To use

```
make xconfig
```

you have to install the QT3 libraries, and you *could* download and install the Precise packages. To do this, download [`libqt3-mt-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libqt3-mt) and install with `sudo dpkg -i`. But you'll have to install many more dependencies.

---

#### But ;)

The only reason you need `qt3` is because you ran `make xconfig`. There are other ways of configuring your kernel for compilation that don't require `qt3`. When I was young, I did it this way:

```
make menuconfig
```

[image]

Or, really old-shool:

```
make config
```

[image]

After the configuration steps, run

```
make -j3
```

if you have two cores (cores + 1)

```
make modules_install
make install
```

Comment: When I was young... I also learnt this method :) +1

Comment: Okay, I still can't fix the "Can't find QT3" problem (tho it seems to be able to settle for QT4 now for some reason tho I have QT5). It seems I can make "make config" work. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the "two cores" comment. That should save me some time.