# Installed libncurses5-dev, but can't make menuconfig!

Tags: kernel, compiling

I installed Kernel and required libraries. I don't know why I'm getting this error

```
batman@tx:~/kernel/linux$ sudo make menuconfig
scripts/kconfig/mconf  Kconfig
init/Kconfig:409: unexpected 'endchoice' within menu block
init/Kconfig:1759: unexpected end statement
make[1]: *** [menuconfig] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

If run without `sudo` I'm getting like below

```
batman@tx:~/kernel/linux$ make menuconfig
 *** Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the
 *** required header files.
 *** 'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.
 *** 
 *** Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again.
 *** 
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Ok, I copied config from `/boot/..`, so I want to continue without configuration. Again, I got this

```
batman@tx:~/kernel/linux$ make -j5 KDEB_PKGVERSION=1.veeru dep-pkg
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
init/Kconfig:409: unexpected 'endchoice' within menu block
init/Kconfig:1759: unexpected end statement
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.
```

In another video, they compiled the kernel like this

```
batman@tx:~/kernel/linux$ fakeroot make-kpkg -j5 --initrd --append-to-version=veeru kernel_image kernel_headers 
exec make kpkg_version=12.036+nmu3 -f /usr/share/kernel-package/ruleset/minimal.mk debian APPEND_TO_VERSION=veeru  INITRD=YES 
====== making target debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian [new prereqs: ]======
This is kernel package version 12.036+nmu3.
test -d debian             || mkdir debian
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘debian’: Permission denied
make: *** [debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian] Error 1
Failed to create a ./debian directory: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/make-kpkg line 984.
```

So, why I'm getting these errors, can someone explain that `make..` command(I know `-j` is for jobs). Most of the times I don't know what I'm doing(What's happening, why I'm doing like, etc). So, is there any articles for newbies like me for GREAT start to know KERNEL stuff :-)

**UPDATE:**

I just want to know, why those errors are coming even I installed the rightpackages([Question HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163298/whats-a-simple-way-to-recompile-the-kernel)). What are the way to compile the Kernel. Why different ways?

Ubuntu 14, Downloaded Kernel from kernel.org(4.2 Release)

Comment: That's very sad, I thought, i could get some answers for this question. But no one post or comment in any stackExchage sites(this, superUser, Unix&Linux) ;-( :-(

Comment: It's way too complicated for me to solve, but atleast you got some likes.

Comment: @StarOS:  Hehehe..yes I got some LIKEs.  You know any sites for good start to learn kernel installation stuff..

Comment: From where did you get the kernel? Which version is it?

Comment: Cross-post at https://superuser.com/questions/994213/installed-libncurses5-dev-but-cant-make-menuconfig and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239827/installed-libncurses5-dev-but-cant-make-menuconfig

Comment: Heck, have a [link](http://kernelnewbies.org/). You want a lot of info - not just how to fix it. That's a good place to start. They've also got some good people there.