# Autoconf kernel, need .config for local build

Tags: kernel, compiling, autoconf

I have a working kernel that was installed as a deb, but it does not have a .config instead it has three files that are autoconf, ect, ect. 
How can I turn this into the current .config to use in a new kernel? Sorry if I don't know all the terminology. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because custom kernels are not supported here...

Comment: You sir, that voted this as off topic are right to do so, but i am a very fresh ubuntu/linux user with a mind to give back to the community, and am working on a patch to fix a very specific problem, with hopes of sending it upstream. I appreciate you seeing this is not the place to ask this, but i ask you give a recommendation of where i can ask this. Kinda sucks to just get the can with no where to turn. be courtious , is all i ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a simple way to recompile the kernel?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163298/whats-a-simple-way-to-recompile-the-kernel)

Comment: You can ask on [unix.se].

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the current kernel you have in your current Ubuntu installation. They are stored in /boot, for example:

```
ls /boot/config*
/boot/config-4.2.0-18-generic  /boot/config-4.3.0-1-generic
/boot/config-4.2.0-19-generic  /boot/config-4.3.0-2-generic
```

and copy the relevant one you want to you top level Linux source directory:

```
cp /boot/config-4.2.0-19-generic .config
```

you can either hand edit the .config or use the menu config tool, e.g.

```
make menuconfig
```

Comment: This file does not exist for the kernel i wish to copy the config from. I installed a kernel image and it has autoconf files where normally there would be a .config. are you saying this would generate it? because it doesnt look like it..

Comment: @Razor_keen: Please use the config of the kernel you *do have* in `/boot`...  And I'm sorry, but I'm just doing my duty to the site here...  Courteous enough???  **;-)**

Comment: Indeed, for the current kernel, use:  cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .

Comment: Strangely enough, the .config was there the whole time. it was in the directory above where i was looking. yes sir courteous enough for me. Mostly cause im happy to find what i was looking for lol. jk