# Ubuntu 14.04.2 kernel version changed after recompiling

Tags: 14.04, kernel, compiling

I have been given an assignment where I have to recompile a 64-bit kernel without any modifications and make the new kernel as the default kernel in grub. I am doing this on an Ubuntu 14.04.2 64-bit system with kernel `3.16.0-60-generic`.

I executed the following instructions (some part followed from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) and some from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/513243/197228)) -

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
cd linux-lts-utopic-3.16.0/
cp /boot/config-3.16.0-60-generic .config
make
make modules
make modules_install
sudo make install
```

I can boot into the kernel and everything but the kernel version (`uname -r`) appears as `3.16.7-ckt22`. How did the version change if I compiled the kernel from `3.16.0-60` sources?

**EDIT**: I did not follow the complete instructions from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel because they overwrite the current kernel image with the new one. I wanted an image with modified suffix like -3.16.0-60-recompiled or something similar and appear alongside the original image in grub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the kernel version didn't change for your compile, it was changed for the official Ubuntu version. Longer answer below.

Official Ubuntu kernels have special version numbers.
You can look up the version number mapping [here](http://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html), and your particular line is copied below:

```
3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1    Ubuntu-lts-3.16.0-60.80_14.04.1 3.16.7-ckt22
```

See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ#Kernel.2BAC8-FAQ.2BAC8-GeneralVersionMeaning.What_does_a_specific_Ubuntu_kernel_version_number_mean.3F) for an explanation of the naming convention, also copied below:

```
What does a specific Ubuntu kernel version number mean?

The official version of an Ubuntu kernel tells you a number of things,
including the base upstream version, the current Ubuntu ABI identifier
and the kernel flavour. (See How can we determine the version of the
running kernel? to find your current version number.)

Given a version like 2.6.35-6.9-generic this can be broken into four
parts as below:

    <base kernel version>-<ABI number>.<upload number>-<flavour> 

The base kernel version represents the mainline version on which the
Ubuntu kernel is based. The ABI number represents significant changes
in the kernel Application Binary Interface. The upload number is a
monotonically increasing counter for each upload of this base version.
The flavour indicates which kernel configuration variant this is (See
What is a Kernel Flavour?).
```