# How to compile a kernel identical to apt-get install linux-image-xxx

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, git, versions

I download kernel source from git://kernel.ubuntu.com/.../ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git. I need to compile version `4.4.0-31-generic` on 14.04.4 lts 64bit, so I clone and checkout branch `Ubuntu-lts-4.4.0-31.50-xxx-14.04.1.I` use `config-4.4.0-31-generic` as config file from `linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic` package. After I compiled, I realize kernel version is 4.4.13 in Makefile and I found arbitrary kernel version config item seems not take effect and installed modules is more than 5000 but package in `linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic` just contain about 1000 modules. The modules I installed size is around 3G, the package just 39M. Am I did it a wrong way?

Comment: @DavidFoerster The first two answers are wrong there. This won't build a debianized Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Please refer to [Aleksadr’s answer](/a/830723/175814) as the others won’t produce the same result that you want.

Comment: @Pilot6: better?

Comment: That's perfect. We need a canonical answer how to build an Ubuntu kernel. People mix up `make` and `debian/rules` way a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You built the kernel a wrong way. The Debian way to build a kernel is:

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

This will build the Ubuntu kernel 4.4.0-31 if you checked out the correct tag.