# Shrink Kernel Size For 64 MB RAM

Tags: kernel, resize

I'm working on reduction of kernel size in Ubuntu. I've compiled and installed the kernel 5.2.3 stable now i want to remove kernel modules manually.

I've tried with rmmod command and after rebooting the Ubuntu it appears again in lsmod list.

I want to reduce kernel size so that i can run stably on 64 MB machines?
Can someone guide me how can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *64MB*? Do you mean *64GB* or *64-bit*? Or is it a specific component that is 64MB?

Comment: I want to make kernel size small so that it can run on 64 MB Ram

Comment: Okay, that makes sense :). Sorry I just didn't understand what you meant by 64MB. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Can you guide me how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

`rmmod` just unloads kernel modules but doesn't remove them from the kernel.

You need to recompile the kernel. See [What's a simple way to recompile the kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163298/whats-a-simple-way-to-recompile-the-kernel)  for how to do that.

When recompiling to have to change the kernel's configuration in the `make menuconfig` or `make xconfig` step and remove the modules and other unneeded features there. The new kernel's configuration isn't affected by `rmmod`.

Comment: Do I've to recompile kernel after unloading the modules?

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify this.